# Microservice, CQRS and BFF Architecture: How to let the bff know about event result data

Tags: nestjs, microservices, cqrs

Im currently implementing a Microservice CQRS architecture with NestJs.
Microservices currently talk through RabbitMQ with each other.
I now want to introduce a BFF.

Problem example: SignUp

When the user signs up, the bff calls the procedure on the auth microservice which dispatches the SignUpUserCommand.
After checking and validating, the bff gets a 201 response (Commands don't return information). The UserSignedUpEvent is triggered inside auth microservice and now persists the user into the database and generates an access and refresh token.

How can the BFF now receive the event result (tokens)? I know it's a practice to let the bff listen to events. Does this mean that the bff must be able to uniquely identify the exact event which corresponds the the api call?

What is a good way to implement the event listening?

Comment: If you need a synchronous response, make the BFF service call the user registration service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response/s!

Yes I did it like that now:
The BFF calls the Microservice (RPC) via the rabbit message queue:

```js
// BFF Application / authentication.controller.ts
constructor(private readonly authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

@Post('/local/signup')
public async signupLocal(@Body() signUpDto: SignUpDto): Promise<AuthTokensDto> {
  return await this.authenticationService.signUpUser(signUpDto);
}
```

```js
// BFF Application / authentication.service.ts
constructor(
  @Inject(RmqChannels.AUTH_SERVICE) private readonly authClient: ClientProxy,
  private readonly apiService: ApiService,
) {}

signUpUser(signUpUserDto: SignUpDto): Promise<AuthTokensDto> {
  return this.apiService.requestTo<AuthTokensDto>(
    this.authClient, // Which microservice to talk to
    signUpUserDto, // Payload for the rpc
    RmqRpcPatterns.SIGN_UP_USER, // The rpc signature
    RmqApiEventPatterns.SIGNED_UP_USER, // Wait for this event to get response
  );
}
```

Inside the BFF Application there is a api.service.ts and an api.controller.ts.
The api.service.ts just forwards the communication. The api.controller.ts just handles the api events and adds them to the event observable:

```js
// BFF Application / api.controller.ts
constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private rmqService: RmqService) {}

@EventPattern(RmqApiEventPatterns.EVENT)
async handleEvent(
  @Payload() payload: RmqEventPayload,
  @Ctx() ctx?: RmqContext): Promise<void> {
    this.apiService.pushEvent(payload);
    if (ctx) this.rmqService.ack(ctx);
    return;
}

// Note: Its listening for 'api_event' pattern
// The exact Api Event Type is inside the RmqEventPayload (signed_up, user_updated,...)
```

Now the delicate part: The api.service.ts makes any type of rpc and listens for a correlating api event (rabbit event).

```js
// BFF Application / api.service.ts
private events: Subject<RmqEventPayload> = new Subject();
private events$ = this.events.asObservable();

public pushEvent(event: RmqEventPayload): void {
  this.events.next(event);
}

requestTo<T>(
  client: ClientProxy,
  dto: any,
  rpc: RmqRpcPatterns,
  apiEvent: RmqApiEventPatterns,
): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // Generating requestId to identify upcoming api event
    const requestId = uuidv4();

    // Creating the rpc payload
    const payload: RmqRpcPayload = {
      requestId,
      dto,
    };

    // Waiting for the associated api event of the to be scheduled rpc call
    this.notifyWhen<T>(apiEvent, requestId).then((result) => {
      resolve(result);
    });

    // Invoking the remote procedure
    const result = await lastValueFrom(client.send(rpc, payload));

    // It result is not true (error in command execution), throw the error it returned
    if (result !== true) {
      // If the result is a known exception code, throw it
      if (Object.values(ExceptionTypesCode).includes(result)) {
        reject(ExceptionUtils.ToHttpException(result));
      } else {
        // else just throw the unknown result
        reject(result);
      }
    }
  });
}

public notifyWhen<T>(
  pattern: RmqApiEventPatterns,
  requestId: string,
): Promise<T> {
  // Returning a promise which waits for the associated api event and parses the result dto
  return firstValueFrom(
    this.events$.pipe(
      filter(
        (apiEvent: RmqEventPayload) =>
          apiEvent.eventPattern === pattern &&
          apiEvent.requestId === requestId,
      ),
      map((apiEvent: RmqEventPayload) => apiEvent.dto),
    ),
  );
}
```

The Microservice RPC returns true when no (rpc) exception was thrown in the command validation process (auth, integrity,...).
When some other Exception was thrown, it translates it to a http exception and throws it

When the async data access/manipulation on the microservice is done, an Rabbit Event is emitted. In the example of the sign up process:

```js
// Microservice Application / signed_up.handler.ts
constructor(
  @Inject(RmqChannels.API_SERVICE) private readonly client: ClientProxy,
) {}
// ... done
const payload: RmqEventPayload = {
  requestId: event.requestId,
  dto: authTokens,
  eventPattern: RmqApiEventPatterns.SIGNED_UP_USER,
};
this.client.emit(RmqApiEventPatterns.EVENT, payload);
```

Hope it's clear enough how the mechanism work.
Here a diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should decide, are u going to use `commands` or `events`. It depends on which type of communication you try to achieve, request/response via message broker or publish/subscribe.

### Request/Response Approach with Commands:

From Nestjs [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics)

> To enable the request-response message type, Nest creates two logical channels - one is responsible for transferring the data while the other waits for incoming responses.

I don't have good experience with `RMQ` and mostly I'm using `Kafka`, but the approach is the same. if you put `SignUpUserCommand` in `registration` topic, you get the reply in `registration.replay` topic. Nest will automatically take care of it .

From Bff you can use:

```
this.client.send(topic, payload) // Observable is returned and you can subscribe to it.
```

Auth microservice:

```
@MessagePattern('registration')
async signUp(data: ...)
```

### Publish/Subscribe Approach with Events:

Bff

```
async signUp(){
    this.client.emit('registration', payload)
}

@EventPattern('registration.complete')
async signUpComplete(data: ...)
```

Auth microservice:

```
@EventPattern('registration')
async signUp(data: ...)

async signUpComplete(){
    this.client.emit('registration.complete', payload)
}
```

Just see the difference between `send` and `emit` in Nestjs [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics).